# How to reload a UITableViewController from another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview, viewcontroller

i would like to reload a tableview from another viewcontroller ( i'm working on PSStackedViewExample https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView ). My UIViewController where i do the modification is a bit on my UITableViewController and i'm doing changement on the data currently on my TableView, it is why i want to reload the tableview to see the changement directly when i modify something on the UIViewController.

I cannot acces to it... everytime i get crazy with this, could you help me ?

on the PSStackedViewExample project, the UITableViewController i'm talking about is ExampleViewController2. 
the UIViewController i'm talking about is : ExampleViewController1

here is some pieces of the code in case you don't downlaod the project :

ExampleMenuRootController which is the main controller, it calls the UITableViewController

the .h first ->

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Guest.h"

@interface ExampleMenuRootController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *menuTable_;
    NSArray *cellContents_;
    singleObjGetData * sObjDataForRootVC;
    UIViewController *viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
- (void)checkDictionnaryForIndexPathForFunction;
-(IBAction)showTable:(id)sender;
- (void)checkDictionnaryForIndexPath:(NSString *)check;
@end
```

the .m  ->

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PSStackedViewController *stackController = XAppDelegate.stackController;
     viewController = nil;

        [sObjDataForRootVC.tmpGuest removeAllObjects];
        [self checkDictionnaryForIndexPath:@"0"];
        [self checkDictionnaryForIndexPath:@"1"];
        [self checkDictionnaryForIndexPath:@"2"];
    if (indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row < 4)
    {
    [sObjDataForRootVC.tmpGuest removeAllObjects];
    [self checkDictionnaryForIndexPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row - 1]];
    }
    if (indexPath.row > 3 && indexPath.row < 8)
    {
        [sObjDataForRootVC.tmpGuest removeAllObjects];
        [self checkDictionnaryForIndexPathForFunction];
    }

    while ([stackController.viewControllers count]) {
        [stackController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

// HERE I CALL THE UITABLEVIEWCONTROLLER !!!

    viewController = [[ExampleViewController2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];     
    ((ExampleViewController2 *)viewController).indexNumber = [stackController.viewControllers count];

    if (viewController) {
        [XAppDelegate.stackController pushViewController:viewController fromViewController:nil animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Then below, the .h of the UIViewController the one which will modify the UITableView. i need to do a reloadData on the tableview from the previous UITableViewController

```
#include "PSStackedViewDelegate.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ExampleViewController1 : UIViewController <PSStackedViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *validateBtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cancelBtn;

    singleObjGetData *sObjDataForRootVC;
}
```

the .m

```
#import "ExampleViewController1.h"
#import "ExampleViewController2.h"
#import "ExampleMenuRootController.h"
#import "PSStackedView.h"

@implementation ExampleViewController1


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    sObjDataForRootVC  = [singleObjGetData singleObj];
    confirmPressed = NO;
    [self setUpView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.width = PSIsIpad() ? 400 : 150;
}
```

Thanks a lot for the helps...

Comment: instead of adding blocks of code(people can download code from the link), add some screenshots which would elaborate what actually your question is

Comment: i don't have access to a ftp server now, i cannot sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up a notification in the second tableview that calls the reloadData on the first tableview. Put this in your second tableView:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"refreshData"
 object:nil
 userInfo:nil//userInfoDictionary
 ];
```

In your first tableView put this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(methodToRefreshYourFirstTable)
 name:@"refreshData"
 object:nil];
```